# Jquery DataTable won't load in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I cannot get a datatable to display in a modal dialog. I get an empty table.

//create the datatable that goes in the modal

```
createTableForModal(selectedLesson);

//show the modal

$('#editLessonModal').modal();
```

**CODE FOR createTableForModal**

```
function createTableForModal()
{
     //this is just example code, but it doesn't work
var dataSet = [
        [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
        [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ]];

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#uploadVideosTable').DataTable( {
                    data: dataSet,
                    columns: [
                        { title: "Name" },
                        { title: "Position" },
                        { title: "Office" },
                        { title: "Extn." },
                        { title: "Start date" },
                        { title: "Salary" }
                    ],retrieve: true,
                } );
            } );
}
```

**HTML FOR DATA TABLE**

```
<table id="uploadVideosTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
               <th>Position</th>
               <th>Office</th>
               <th>Extn.</th>
               <th>Start Date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
             </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Any console errors??

Comment: Nope, there was not any console errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JQuery DataTable **cannot initialize `<table>` elements that are not visible on the screen**. You must first "show" the element (maybe via the `.show()` function), before invoking the table initialization. In this case that it is inside a Bootstrap Modal (which is hidden on load by default), it will fail to initialize. @ShriCoder 's code will work just fine, but the problem is it will throw an error if you open the modal second time around saying something of "DataTable cannot be reinitialized". I would suggest you to revise your code, either:

1. Make your `modal` initially visible on load, initialize your  `<table>` then hide your modal. It will take some milliseconds, and your Users wouldn't normally notice.
2. Initialize your `<table>` **once** during a `shown.bs.modal` event fired by the modal. You may check if the `<table>` is already initialized by either using the plugin's internal [`$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()) utility function, or checking if your `<table>` has already a "dataTable" css class.

---

On the side note, please also use the plug-in's separate `.js` and `.css` utility files for BootStrap compatibility. It optimizes your `<table>` (user's expirience-wise) to fit perfectly on webpages that use BootStrap.

Answer (score 1):

Call your createTableForModal(selectedLesson) function inside below code:

```
$('#code').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  //Call your Function here 
});
```

it will work. if its not working still post jsfiddle i will check