# How to load the DataTable jQuery plugin when a Bootstrap modal window is completely loaded without getting asynchronous issues?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, bootstrap-modal

I am currently using Bootstrap v4.4.1 and the nodejs bootstrap versions of the plugin:

```
require('datatables.net-bs4')(window, $);
require('datatables.net-colreorder-bs4')(window, $);
require('datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4')(window, $);
```

First I load all the rows in the table that is inside the html of the Bootstrap modal window. All these operations are synchronous, so I don't see any issue here. Each one of the functions `get_*` just add node elements with jQuery.

```
for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    var col_name = cols[i];
    var name = self.get_col_name(col_name);
    var data_type = self.get_data_type(col_name)
    var attrs = self.pj_cols[col_name]['attrs'].join(', ');  // TODO: translate to icons or extract just some of them?
    var cb_export = self.get_cb_export(i, col_name);
    var sel_cur_prec = self.get_cur_prec(col_name);
    var txt_cur_unit = self.get_txt_cur_unit(col_name);
    var set_bt = self.get_set_bt(col_name, i);

    var tr = $('<tr>');
    tr.append(
        $('<td>', {html: cb_export }),
        name,
        $('<td>', {html: data_type }),
        $('<td>', {text: attrs }),
        $('<td>', {html: sel_cur_prec }),
        $('<td>', {html: txt_cur_unit }),
        $('<td>', {html: set_bt })
    );
    $('#table_column_project tbody').append(tr);
}
```

Then I load the modal window programmatically by clicking the button to trigger and show it

```
$('#modal_column_project').click();
```

And finally I run the `DataTable()` function in order to convert the table in a DataTable

```
$('#column_project_win').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#table_column_project').DataTable( {
        scrollY: 400,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging: false,
        searching: true,
        ordering: true,
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        info: false,
        columnDefs: [
            { targets: '_all', visible: true, },
            { targets: [6], orderable: false, searchable: false, },
            { targets: [0, 2, 4, 5, 6], type: 'html'}
        ],
        initComplete: function () {
            // initially the div which is a containter has opacity 0
            $('#div_column_project').animate({ opacity: 1, }, { duration: 100, });
        },
    });
});
```

This is working well just sometimes. Often, the rows never appear and the DataTable shows the message:

```
No matching records found
```

Is there a way to do this better in order to avoid this asynchronous issue? I say asynchronous because apparently is random.

I have also tried to add this hack without good results. I think the problem is in the DataTable call where the table rows are removed

```
var _check_loaded_rows = setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#table_column_project tbody tr').length == cols.length) {  // check if all rows are correctly loaded
        clearInterval(_check_loaded_rows);
        $('#table_column_project').DataTable( {  // TODO: show only when rendered
            scrollY: 400,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: false,
            searching: true,
            ordering: true,
            order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],  // this is the value by default
            info: false,
            columnDefs: [
                { targets: '_all', visible: true, },
                { targets: [6], orderable: false, searchable: false, },
                { targets: [0, 2, 4, 5, 6], type: 'html'}
            ],
            initComplete: function () {
                $('#div_column_project').animate({ opacity: 1, }, { duration: 100, });
            },
        });
    }
}, 100);
```

Actually, now I have a `setTimeout` with 500ms of delay to make it work well.

I have also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37827702/4891717) where the poster recommends that we should use the bootstrap version, the table should be initialized (I use `opacity` to hide it, instead of `display: none;`) and to show the DataTable I use the builtin method `initComplete` to run the instruction to set the opacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have a few hundred rows, why not insert them using the API in `initComplete`? You can pass the API to another function (like the one using `get_*` methods you already use to populate (it is unclear if it is a function or not)) :

```js
function populate(api) {
  for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    ...
    api.row.add([cb_export, name, data_type, attrs, sel_cur_prec, txt_cur_unit, set_bt])
  }
  api.draw/()
}

$('#table_column_project').DataTable({
  ...
  initComplete: function() {
    const api = this.api()
    populate(api)
  }
})
```

Or, you can use a promise and wait for that inside the modal event handler:

```js
function populate() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    ...
    if (i+1 === cols.length) resolve()
  })
}

$('#column_project_win').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  populate().then(() => {
    $('#table_column_project').DataTable( {
      ...
    })
  })
})
```

If you not have Promise available in your nodejs (older versions) you can use for example `es6-promise` and

```js
const Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise
```

Comment: Thank you I like the solution of adding the elements in `initComplete`. As some of the elements were html code I had to add them with `sel_cur_prec.prop('outerHTML')`

Comment: Sadly I am still having the same issue, something may be wrong with the `initComplete` function, I don't know

Comment: Hey @ChesuCR can you setup a fiddle replicating the problem?

Comment: Here is a starting point -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/

Comment: I doubt there is a problem with the initComplete callback. I have the feeling you are coming from another env and expect things to be as it was in the good old days. You should carefully do as instructed in the docs. DT is a very complicated task which takes data and handle it in many ways, it is not originally meant to run on nodejs but **can** run with nodejs. Any error in the console is important.

Comment: Thanks for your interes. Replicating the environment in a fiddle is difficult I believe, with all the specific versions. But the code is public, you can check the DataTable declaration [here](https://github.com/ocean-data-qc/ocean-data-qc/blob/master/ocean_data_qc_js/src/js/modals_renderer/column_project.js#L67). If you take a look I will appreciate it

Comment: @ChesuCR, I'll do it when I come home!